# How can I detect what version of JavaDB/Derby I'm using?

Tags: jar, version, javadb, derby

I use JavaDB (Derby) as an embedded database in my Java Swing application. I would like to detect and print the version of JavaDB I'm using. I have included `derby.jar` in my .jar-file for the application.

How can I detect and print the version of my embedded JavaDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/javadoc/jdbc3/org/apache/derby/tools/sysinfo.html

```
String version = sysinfo.getVersionString();
```

Can also be run from the command line:

```
java -jar yourjarfile.jar org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo
```

If you do not want the compile-time dependency, you can also get the version info from the [JDBC DatabaseMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html):

```
 conn.getMetaData().getDatabaseMajorVersion(); // and friends
```

Comment: Thanks. `conn.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductVersion();` provided the most specific information, `10.5.1.1 - (764942)`.

Comment: Is there a SQL query that can return similar info? Something like SELECT @@VERSION (SQL Server) and SELECT VERSION() (MySQL)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also [detect the product version directly using SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/2021/05/12/how-to-get-an-rdbms-server-version-with-sql/):

```sql
select getdatabaseproductversion() from (values (1)) t (a);
```